# Why do I get a 405 error when making an http request when testing an app on a remote server?

Tags: angular, nginx, deployment

I am trying to identify the reason why when making an http request in the staging context I get a 405 error. While when trying the same scenario locally I get a 200

I show the relevant components

proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/connect/*": {
    "target": "http://portal.test.com/backend",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

login.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginService {
  private readonly ENDPOINT = '/connect/token';

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  login(credentials: CredentialsModel): Observable<SuccessfulLoginModel> {
    const { username, password } = credentials;
    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('grant_type', 'password');
    body.set('username', username);
    body.set('password', password);
    body.set('scope', 'offline_access openid profile');
    const options = this.getHTTPOptions();

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.ENDPOINT, body.toString(), options);
  }

  refreshToken(token: string): Observable<SuccessfulLoginModel> {
    // ...
  }

  private getHTTPOptions() {
    return {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .set(
          'Authorization',
          'Basic ' +
            btoa(`${environment.client_id}:${environment.client_secret}`)
        ),
    };
  }
}
```

Locally when calling to `/connect/token` endpoint I get the following response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: OrchardCore
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
server: nginx/1.23.1
date: Sun, 13 Nov 2022 01:46:27 GMT
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 12337
cache-control: no-store
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
set-cookie: .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/backend; samesite=lax; httponly
x-content-type-options: nosniff
referrer-policy: no-referrer
connection: close
```

In staging when calling the /connect/token endpoint I get the following response

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
server: nginx/1.23.1
date: Sun, 13 Nov 2022 01:48:19 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 157
```

Can you help me with some indication of the reason for this behavior. Thanks in advance

## update 1

I have reproduced the behavior on the remote server. Using docker I have mounted and configured an nginx instance,

```
docker run --name habanos -v /home/mario/projects/spa/dist/app-name:/usr/share/nginx/html/:ro -d -p 8080:80 nginx:latest
```

Following angular documentation I setup the recommended [front controller pattern Web apps](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples)

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

The above makes the application accessible. This is where when trying an http POST request I get the behavior of getting 405

Setting `error_page 405 =200 $uri;` change 405 to 200r but still getting html content

How to properly configure nginx to handle POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem has been to use the base url in the proxy configuration

The original target url was the following:

```
{
  "/connect/*": {
    "target": "http://portal.test.com/backend",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Using the base url as the target url fixed the problem

```
{
  "/backend/*": {
    "target": "http://portal.test.com",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

In this way, the endpoints invoked from the services look similar to the following:

```
private readonly ENDPOINT = '/backend/connect/token';
```